# How to Manage Multiple NFTS (ERC721) using just one contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency

Most NFT code are more or like similar, so every time I want to create a new type/genre for an NFT I would have to upload a new Contract?  Can't I just create just one contract with a property like edition/series/season/etc.. to manage every foreseen type is that possible or will it interfere with markets/rules or something.? Any Ideas how to manage a thing like that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this with the ERC1155 multi token standard, it is one contract that can manage both fungible and non fungible tokens in one single deploy